# Spring RequestMapping 404 error

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404

I'm start new project in gradle. but continuously url mapping error come up. 
This is a 404 error.
i'm try this error catch but this error don't understand please answer 
I'm not good at English. If you have any grammar errors, please understand me.

Controller

```
package sample.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeContoller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }


}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="false">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- *.do -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- *.json-->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

dispacher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="sample">
      <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
                              expression="sample.controller.json.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
         <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

applicaion-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="sample">
      <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" 
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="mapperLocations" 
                value="classpath*:sql/*Mapper.xml" />
      <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="sample.vo" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="sample.dao" />
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

Comment: what URL are you using to check it?

Comment: What url are you trying to access ? and do you have the servlet-mapping for the url ? This seems to be the issue.

Comment: error image url : http://imgur.com/AZXyr7P  file tree url : http://imgur.com/3Tkrc7z please answer

Comment: i use tomcat 8 url is localhost:8080/sample1/home.do

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change your url from `basepath/home.do` to `basepath/home` or change mapping from `/home` to `/home.do`. That should work.

Comment: controllor mapping value change? Or browser URL change? sorry i don't understand..

Comment: Change `@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)`  to `@RequestMapping(value = "/home.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: Unfortunately mapping value changed 404 error run TT

Comment: Can you post current `web.xml` and `controller` code after changes?

Comment: How do I raise the code? new ask question? sorry this question stackoverflow first question

Comment: Go to `web.xml` and modify `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>` . Rest all should work fine then.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'm sorry, <url-pattern> change but  there's  Tomcat error.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Comment thank you sir i'm this problem not solved 
Eclipse consol log is Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]

Comment: Please visit my github repository if you like.
clone URL is https://github.com/sondeokhyeon/sample.git

Comment: Tomcat 8005 port error is my mistake .. 
 I change Tomcat version, it runs a 404 error.